# WPF Handling Window taskbar closing event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem in a WPF Application. When I close my application from the Window task bar (*Close window*) or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> it never hits the `Application_exit` event handler in my App.xaml file.

```xml
<Application x:Class="WPFApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"             
             Startup="Application_Startup" Exit="Application_Exit">
```

Code behind

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your XAML have a *StartupUri* attribute ?

Comment: Why not use `this.Close()`? It calls `Application.Current.Shutdown()`. Also, you may need a return statement after your `Application.Current.Shutdown()`, but I can't remember for sure if that's necessary.

Comment: @AmatuerDev No i am just using Startup in App.xaml file. and it back end Call LOGIN Form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably set

```
ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
```

on your App.xaml (or in code behind).

Therefore you need to set a listener on the Closed event of your MainWindow, which is calling the shutdown method.

Or you have set

```
ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose"
```

Then you probably have some window open, besides the MainWindow.

Answer (score -1):

Your event handler currently shuts down your app:

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {

    Application.Current.Shutdown();

    }
```

But if you want to do something, your should add it before `Application.Current.Shutdown();'
For example:

```
`private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
        {
        //Do something here, delete unused files etc...
        Application.Current.Shutdown();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Ling for comments. My problem is when i Pressed ALT + F4 keys any where in my Application it close that form but it does't hit This Application_Exit Function. How i possible it when i Pressed Alt+F4 or Close Window from Task Bar it shutdown my Application. 
Thanks

Comment: Ivan Ling's answer doesn't refer to the original question.